# C# code for best-fit circle

Tags: c#

I would like C# code for determining the centre and radius of the circle that best fits the points in an array using the least squares method or equivalent.

Having searched on web I've found none.

Comment: Do you have the formula for this?  Have you tried writing something?

Comment: Is this homework? If so please tag it as such

Comment: how about you calculate the mid-point (average of all points) and then look for the maximum distance between the mid-point and the rest of the points (which will yield your radius)? sounds pretty easy to me

Comment: non maximum, but **minimum** distance from the center of gravity of the point cloud to on of the vertices in the cloud.

Comment: @Tigran If I got the OP right he`s looking into finding the circle that covers up all of the points, i.e all of the points are inside the circle, so it's maximum - not minimum; maybe I'm getting him wrong though.

Comment: @Shai: I unerstood an *inverse*: all points are **out** or **on** circle.

Comment: @Tigran in that case, you are correct! :-) in the other case, it's maximum, anyhow the OP should revise the question

Comment: You both missunderstand him - He wants to find the circle where the sum of all distance squared from the circle edge to the point is as small as possible (least squares method minimizes the squared error)

Comment: @Shai, thanks but that fails e.g. when there are more points on one side of the circle than the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use a general minimization algorithm such as [Levenberg-Marquardt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) or turn it into a linear problem and just solve for the parameters of the circle (x,y, radius). See this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214661/circle-least-squares-fit) for more information.

I'm not aware of any multivaraible [Levenberg-Marquardt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) for .NET so the second solution is probably easier to go for. Note that you will need to solve a matrix equation of the form Ax=b to find your circle parameters. The Math.NET library seems able to [do this](http://iridium.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra/Matrix.htm#Solve).

Comment: in case someone runs across this, ALGLIB has a Levenberg-Marquardt multivariate solver.

Comment: Indeed, it does. That helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the FitEllipse function of the opencv library : 
[Fit ellipse](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=fitellipse#RotatedRect%20fitEllipse%28InputArray%20points%29)

I think a C# wrapper of OpenCV exists.